# No image and title when sharing my blog post on LinkedIn

Tags: wordpress, apache, https, share, linkedin-api

While I'm trying to share a post from my blog on **Linkedin**, I don't see the **thumbnail image** and the title of the post. Not see it both on Linkedin's preview window or in the **Linkedin's** feed, after sharing it.

I do have correct og meta description (Using **Yost SEO Plugin**) on my page.
When I'm trying to share the same page via **Facebook** it is working perfectly well.

It seems like, from some reason Linkedin not "reading" my website and see my meta data.

**The post I'm trying to share is:**

https://www.zoliro.com/topi-and-zoliro-event-bag-announce-strategic-partnership/

(But the same problem happening when trying to share any other post from my blog)

**and you can see below that I have correct meta data:**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Topi and Zoliro announce strategic partnership" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Announcement - Together Topi and Zoliro - the digital event bag, will combine forces to conquer decreasing attention spans and work with event organizers to bring in-event attendee engagement to the next level." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.zoliro.com/topi-and-zoliro-event-bag-announce-strategic-partnership/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Zoliro" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.zoliro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Topi-strategic-partnership-announcement.png" />
```

I think it's may be connected to the "**HTTPS**" because if I'm trying to share from my test site on (**Which I'm not using SSL there**):

http://ws-test.zoliro.com/ben-scheim-best-addition-to-your-sponsorship-package/

It's working.

Is anyone here can advise with that issue please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, our dev team has figured it out:
On the default config file of our Apache server, our domain was defined as a naked domain (*domainname.com*) while on our **Wordpress** config file, the domain was defined as a full domain (*www.domainname.com*).

Apparently, for **Linkedin** it looks like we forced him to do a redirect to another host and **Linkedin** doesn't support that.

After we'd defined all configs as full domain it works perfectly.